# How do I pick one dict inside a list of dictionaries that are differed by one value?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries like this:

```
xyz =[ {"key1":"1","key2":"2","key3":"x_1"},{"key1":"1","key2":"2","key3":"x_2"},{"key1":"1","key2":"2","key3":"x_3"},{"key1":"5","key2":"6","key3":"y_1"},{"key1":"5","key2":"6","key3":"y_2"},{"key1":"5","key2":"6","key3":"y_3"}]
```

I am trying to select first dict for every unique 'key1' value. For the above dict I am expecting an output as:

```
 xyz=[{"key1":"1","key2":"2","key3":"x_1"},{"key1":"5","key2":"6","key3":"y_1"},]
```

I tried the following code:

```
dictout = [dict(sample) for sample in set(tuple(item.items()) for item in xyz)]
```

But I ended up getting:

```
[{'key3': 'x_1', 'key2': '2', 'key1': '1'}, {'key3': 'x_3', 'key2': '2', 'key1': '1'}, {'key3': 'y_2', 'key2': '6', 'key1': '5'}, {'key3': 'x_2', 'key2': '2', 'key1': '1'}, {'key3': 'y_1', 'key2': '6', 'key1': '5'}, {'key3': 'y_3', 'key2': '6', 'key1': '5'}]
```

I am not able to construct unique dicts based on the value of "key1".

It would be great if someone gives me an idea to approach.

Thank you.

Comment: So what've you tried?

Comment: Does it have to be the *first* one and/or do you care about the order? `{d['key1']: d for d in xyz}` to deduplicate, then optionally turn it back into a list (→ `.values()`).

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: @Rogalski couldn't help imagining clippy saying that.

Comment: @Rogalski I am really sorry if my question sounded like that. I edited with what I have tried. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) from the [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html) library:

```
import itertools

xyz =[ {"key1":"1","key2":"2","key3":"x_1"},{"key1":"1","key2":"2","key3":"x_2"},
       {"key1":"1","key2":"2","key3":"x_3"},{"key1":"5","key2":"6","key3":"y_1"},
       {"key1":"5","key2":"6","key3":"y_2"},{"key1":"5","key2":"6","key3":"y_3"}]

result = []
for key, value in itertools.groupby(xyz, lambda x: x["key1"]):
    result.append(list(value))

print([x[0] for x in result])
```

Output:

```
[{'key1': '1', 'key2': '2', 'key3': 'x_1'}, {'key1': '5', 'key2': '6', 'key3': 'y_1'}]
```

Or even with list comprehension:

```
result = [list(value) for key, value in itertools.groupby(xyz, lambda x: x["key1"])]
```

You can also use [`itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html?highlight=itemgetter#operator.itemgetter) from the [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html) library:

```
import operator
import itertools

result = [list(value) for key, value in itertools.groupby(xyz, operator.itemgetter("key1")]
```

You can also use another dictionary too:

```
d = {}
for key, value in itertools.groupby(xyz, lambda x: x["key1"]):
    d[key] = list(value)

print([value[0] for key, value in sorted(d.items())])
```